# ARM assembly recursive power function

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, arm

Need to convert the following C code into ARM assembly subroutine:

```
 int power(int x, unsigned int n) 
 {          
   int y; 
   if (n == 0)  
     return 1; 
   if (n & 1) 
     return x * power(x, n - 1); 
   else 
   { y = power(x, n >> 1); 
     return y * y; 
   } 
 }
```

Here's what I have so far but cant figure out how to get the link register to increment after each return (keeps looping back to the same point)

```
pow             CMP             r0, #0
                MOVEQ           r0, #1
                BXEQ            lr
                TST             r0, #1
                BEQ             skip
                SUB             r0, r0, #1
                BL              pow
                MUL             r0, r1, r0
                BX              lr
skip            LSR             r0, #1
                BL              pow
                MUL             r3, r0, r3
                BX              lr
```

Comment: Recursive function would need to have *some* stack usage...

Comment: link register is only one (think of it like global variable in high level language), i.e. the very first subroutine call will exhaust its storage potential. For further subroutine calls you will have to first "empty" it by copying the link register value into some other storage, then calling the subroutine (which will replace the link register value with new one), then restore previous. Because of recursion the possible call-depth is unlimited, so you will need dynamic storage for those linked-register values. Usually "stack memory" concept is used for this kind of tasks, read some tutorial.

Comment: And you will have to also store/restore any other register values, which are locally used, so the recursive sub-call will not destroy your current values. With smart rearranging of code you can often minimize the local values which need to be preserved = minimizing the total amount of storage per nested-call, improving the possible limit of maximal depth (which is limited by amount of free stack memory). With `power` function you don't need to worry about maximum depth (if `n` is 32 bit, then 32 is max depth, should fit into stack even if you use it carelessly).

Comment: @EugeneSh. A sane way to implement this would be tail-recursive, which does *not* require multiple stack frames, and can be done using only caller-saved registers in the default ARM calling convention.

Comment: @EOF That would be iterative.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If words don't have any meaning to you, then you can call it iterative.

Comment: @EOF Please explain, how a tail recursion (or to be more precise - an optimized tail recursion) is different from loop. It will not perform a self *call*, it will perform a *jump* to it's start. Which is a loop. Tail recursion *is* a recursion with all of the consequences including the space complexity. It is just such a nice kind of recursion which can be easily optimized to be a loop without this space complexity.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Clearly tail-*recursion* is recursion. It's part of the name. If it compiles to the same assembly sequence as an iteration statement that does not make it an iteration statement.

Comment: @EOF We are not talking here about what the C code is compiling to but about the direct Asm implementation. You are suggesting to implement it as an iteration and call it tail recursion. I think it might be not clear enough what the OP is asking - to have a recursive ASM function or have just some ASM function with the same result.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, but if I replace the `bx func; bx lr;` at the end of my hand-written assembly with `b func`, I will continue calling the code tail-recursive, because that is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `BL` instruction does not automatically push or pop anything from the stack. This saves a memory access. It's the way it works with RISC processors (in part because they offer 30 general purpose registers.)

```
STR   lr, [sp, #-4]!   ; "PUSH lr"
BL    pow
LDR   lr, [sp], #4     ; "POP lr"
```

If you repeat a `BL` call, then you want to `STR`/`LDR` on the stack outside of the loop.

Comment: *Which* RISC architecture(s) offer 30 registers? Not SPARC, not MIPS, and certainly not ARM.

Comment: Out of the 32, there are 2 that are used for things that you cannot in any way change, so you are stuck with 30. There are generally 1 or 2 others used for things you can't change either, but those registers are still somewhat available.

Comment: SPARC has a variable number of registers that are available in register windows. MIPS *does* have 3**1** GPRs. 32-bit ARM has a whopping **15** GPRs (some of which are banked for exceptions).